# What is the correct way to use weights in a logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, spss, glm

My data includes survey data of car buyers. My data has a weight column that i used in SPSS to get sample sizes. Weight column is affected by demographic factors & vehicle sales. Now i am trying to put together a logistic regression model for a car segment which includes a few vehicles. I want to use the weight column in the logistic regression model & i tried to do so using "weights" in glm function. But the results are horrific. Deviances are too high, McFadden Rsquare too low. My dependent variable is binary, independent variables are on 1 to 5 scale. Weight column is numerical, ranging from 32 to 197. Could that be a reason that results are poor? Do i need to have values in weight column below 1?

Format of input file to R is -

```
WGT output I1 I2 I3 I4 I5
67   1      1  3  1  5  4
```

I1, I2, I3 being independent variables

```
logr<-glm(output~1,data=data1,weights=WGT,family="binomial")

logrstep<-step(logr,direction = "both",scope = formula(data1))\

logr1<-glm(output~ (formula from final iteration),weights = WGT,data=data1,family="binomial")

hl <- hoslem.test(data1$output,fitted(logr1),g=10)
```

I want a logistic regression model with better accuracy & gain a better understanding of using weights with logistic regression

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the `survey` package. This will allow you to specify weights for the survey design using the `svydesign` function. Additionally, you can use the `svyglm` function to perform your weighted logistic regression. See http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/

Something like the following assuming your data is in a dataframe called `df`

```
my_svy <- svydesign(df, ids = ~1, weights = ~WGT)
```

Then you can do the following:

```
my_fit <- svyglm(output ~1, my_svy, family = "binomial")
```

For a full reprex check out the below example

```
library(survey)

# Generate Some Random Weights
mtcars$wts <- rnorm(nrow(mtcars), 50, 5)

# Make vs a factor just for illustrative purposes
mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)

# Build the Complete survey Object
svy_df <- svydesign(data = mtcars, ids = ~1, weights = ~wts)

# Fit the logistic regression
fit <- svyglm(vs ~ gear + disp, svy_df, family = "binomial")

# Store the summary object
(fit_sumz <- summary(fit))

# Look at the AIC if desired
AIC(fit)

# Pull out the deviance if desired
fit_sumz$deviance
```

As far as the stepwise regression, this typically isn't a great methodology for a statistical point of view. It results in a higher R2 and some other issues regarding inference (see https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/).

Comment: I am facing issue with "step" function, using which i run the iterations for logistic regression. I am getting the following message - "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'ER_VEH' not found" ER_VEH is the name of my output variable

Comment: I will also add my code -                                                                                                        my_svy <- svydesign(data = data1,ids = ~1, weights = ~WGT_REG)                                logr <- svyglm(ER_VEH ~1, my_svy, family = "quasibinomial")
logrstep<-step(logr,direction = "both",scope = formula(data1))

Comment: my_svy <- svydesign(data = data1,ids = ~1, weights = ~WGT_REG)

logr<-glm(ER_VEH ~ 1,data=data1,family="binomial")

logrstep<-step(logr,direction = "both",scope = formula(data1))

logr_survey <- svyglm(ER_VEH ~ all selected variables from last iteration of step, design=my_svy, family = "binomial")
summary(logr_survey)                                                                                                  I tried to use weights at the last step, is this correct approach? I didnt get any deviance scores at end of summary like normal logistic regression output.

Comment: @RaghuNandan see the updated answer with a reprex. As far as the stepwise regression, if that is the approach that you wanted to take I think what you describe is fine, but still has the other issues associated with stepwise regression in general

Comment: Thanks for the example. I understand that stepwise is not the best way possible for Logistic regression. My problem is i have around 50 independent variables. Would you suggest me to use Regularization techniques such as LASSO to eliminate a few nonsignificant variables & then bring those variables into survey package to get final output ?

Comment: & if you suggest me to use LASSO then at which step i should use my weight variable? while doing LASSO OR after selecting final variables from LASSO & in final survey model ?

Comment: @RaghuNandan you can use weights directly in the ``cv.glmnet()`` function with the ``weights argument`` from the ``glmnet`` library. I would go that route if you were looking for a better method (see <https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html#log>> for more details